# Jquery or json load data without refreshing page and add into html tags

Tags: html, json, tags

I get some data on html/php page from database. And I edit it. But I want that data to change automatically without refreshing when I edit and click submit button. I have read that I must use json. But I can't add json values into html tags.

How can I do it ?

If you could not understand me, see this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_7oYeNU_3g&list=LLlqWRsgR9-MVVtE0O5qQUEA&index=13).

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript to fetch the json file and manipulate the DOM accordingly. The example you provided uses jquery. Jquery provides a couple of ways to retrieve json data with ajax calls. This is all documented very well. See https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: what is difference between get and load ? load makes empty tag which is related. get also do like that? if i write $(".mydv").load(".file.php"); mydiv will empty and get content of file.php . get() also does it ?